# os.path.exists() doesn't work in storm.py script even though the path exists

Tags: java, python, real-time, apache-storm

storm.py script prints

> "ERROR:  JAVA_HOME is invalid.  Could not find bin/java at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04."

even though the path exists. Same piece of code (subset of storm.py) runs fine when kept and run through a different script.

Piece of Code:

```
JAVA_HOME = os.getenv('JAVA_HOME', None)
JAVA_CMD = 'java' if not JAVA_HOME else os.path.join(JAVA_HOME, 'bin', 'java')
if JAVA_HOME and not os.path.exists(JAVA_CMD):
    print("ERROR:  JAVA_HOME is invalid.  Could not find bin/java at %s." % JAVA_HOME)
    sys.exit(1)
```

What could be the possible cause and solution for this issue?
I am using windows7 64 bit, python 2.6, java7.

Comment: make sure JAVA_HOME variable is pointing to the home directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04. in your System variables

Comment: Print the value of JAVA_CMD.  That's what the real problem is.

Comment: yes, JAVA_HOME is fine. when I echo or print it's correct moreover it's running perfectly fine when I run this code from temp.py file. JAVA_CMD=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\java this is also fine.